# Anticipatory “it” representing the object in a gerundial phrase

Tags: objects

Can anyone explain to me why we need the dummy “it” in the sentence 1 and 2, but not in 3 and 4?

1– We found it very useless trying to persuade him to go with us.

2– I don’t think it worthwhile taking such trouble.

3– I don’t recall ever saying such a thing.

4– We must practice speaking English every day.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both 1 and 2, they follow a more general pattern of "X, Ying...". In this pattern, "X" is a comment/subjective statement (and a complete sentence), and "Ying..." describes the action the comment is about. This pattern, in writing, is mostly used to highlight the comment, or (IMO, more often) in speech when you realize your comment may be misinterpreted. For example, you might say "That sucks, being kicked out." You originally said "that sucks" but then you realized you weren't clear, so you add "being kicked out" to make it clear.

Now, with this established, note that "X" needs to be a complete comment that is grammatical on its own right. Based on your examples, "We found it very useless" is grammatical, but if we get rid of "it" we get "We found very useless" which is not grammatically correct. Similarly, "I don’t think it worthwhile" requires the "it" since "I don't think worthwhile" isn't grammatical.

3 and 4 don't follow this pattern, so lets look at them individually. In 3, if you say "I don’t recall **it** ever saying such a thing" it implies you are talking about some inanimate object doing the talking. Implicitly, without the "it" the meaning is "I don't recall **myself** ever saying such a thing." In general, we can drop the reflexives, and only include them when we need to clarify or emphasize something.

In 4, there is nowhere for "it" to even go, as far as I can see. You could rephrase to "We must practice **it** every day" but beyond that I don't know where you believe "it" could go.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. 
You are right the sentence 4 is a bad example.
I’m having problems to use the anticipatory object because in my native language we don’t have it.
So, for what I understand, we use the anticipatory object when a word or a phrase come in between the verb and the real object.

Answer (score -1):

1 and 2 work because they support the structure: *[ verb + object + adjective ]*, where the anticipatory "it" has the role of *object* and because it makes sense to use anticipatory "it" in that context.

In 3, the verb "recall" does have the structure *[ "recall" + optional object + "-ing" phrase with "to" + base form ]*, which allows anticipatory "it", but in the context of your example sentence, it's the wrong structure to use.

First, let's rephrase 3 to include the *optional object*:

> I don’t recall **myself** ever saying such a thing.

I hope it's clear to you that it would be impossible to replace "myself" with an anticipatory "it" since the antecedent "I" has already been named, and there's no *"to"-base form* phrase.

So let's take a completely different context where "recall" and anticipatory "it" work together:

> I don't recall **it** ever taking so long **to get downtown**.

Here, "it" anticipates "*to get downtown*". To show this is true, let's reword it without "it" while keeping the exact same meaning:

> I don't recall **getting downtown** ever taking so long.

4 doesn't work because it doesn't support this structure at all -- I can't even guess where you would expect it to appear.

Comment: Downvote, but no comment?